# Granting access to a keychain item across reboots/updates etc

Tags: objective-c, macos, password-protection, keychain, password-encryption

I am developing an app for Mac OSX, which is supposed to store sensitive information in a password-protected file. The app asks the user to set up a secure password (say, during the setup).
I would like the app to be able to keep storing information in the encrypted file without having to ask the user for the password each time some new information is added, or even when the app is restarted, the system is rebooted or the app is updated, but only when a user wants to access the encrypted file.

Is there a "common practice" scheme to do this? I know about the keychain, that's where I'm storing the password now, my problem is that the app should be granted access to that keychain item once and for all.

Comment: If it is your app that stores the password into the keychain, it will be granted access to it "once and for all". Well, not literally of course as the user or OS X always could revoke the permission, but it's probably safe to assume that both won't do without a reason.

Comment: Okay, but once the app has access to the keychain, how do I make it ask for the password when the user wants to access the file?

Comment: what a silly question, I got it.